# C#/DataTable/DataGrid/SQL - How can I insert Params into a stored procedure from DataGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Thank you for taking you time to read this. Basically what I am trying to do is return details on [Issues] that gets pulled from the DB via a stored procedure

There are 2 parameters, `[IssueNo]` and `[LineNo]`. When I click on a button the program needs to return the details eg: ItemName, Code etc for each DataGridRow that I select, BUT what it currently does is return the LAST [Issues] details instead of the one I am selecting in the grid.

I know that my stored procedure is correct but somewhere in my C# code the parameters are not getting the value for every row I select. Only ONE and its still the wrong one

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
{
    IssueNo = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
    TranLineNo = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1].ToString()); 
}

detailsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IssueNo", IssueNo);
detailsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TranLineNo", TranLineNo);
DetailsIssue details1 = new DetailsIssue();

SqlDataAdapter Idetails = new SqlDataAdapter(detailsCmd);
Idetails.Fill(detailsReturned);

details1.dgvIssuesDetail.DataSource = detailsReturned;
details1.Show();
```

That is the code for finding the parameters for the stored procedure.

https://prnt.sc/qybxvs here is what the app looks like, the red is the row selected and the the details buttons clicked once clicked it passes the IssueNo and the TranLineNo in black to the stored procedure which then returns the Details for the Issue that's selected. it returns the correct data idea but for the wrong issue. And if I select multiple rows it still only returns one

If you need any other additional information please feel free to ask. I patiently await your reply

Comment: First of all you are passing without "@", which is invalid. Please use detailsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssueNo", IssueNo);
secondly your mention link is not working "https://prnt.sc/qybxvs"

Comment: @MashhadSaleem the fast that i am passing without '@' makes no difference, i might not have 7 years of experience as it says in your profile but i have no issues with my code as i did get it to work the way that i want it to work , also the reference link does work i just checked it again but its no longer needed. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i am not exactly sure how i fixed it but here is what i changed and now it works, so for anyone with the same issue this is what i did to fix the problem above, maybe someone can explain what i did better than i can

```
DataTable issueView = new DataTable();
SqlConnection issueConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
issueConn.Open();
SqlCommand issueCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Populate_Issue_View", issueConn)
{
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
};
if (chkHideReturned.Checked == true)
{
    issueCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Codefrom", 100);
    issueCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Codeto", 100);

}
else
{
    issueCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Codefrom", 100);
    issueCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Codeto", 120);
}
SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(issueCmd);
da2.Fill(issueView);
dataGridView2.DataSource = issueView;
```

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) and [this](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I have seen those before and i know that sp_ is not needed but its the way our company structures thier StoredProcs so i just follow the lead. and the AddWithValue, i use that because higher up in the Code i have already defined the datatype so when parsing to SQL there are no issues, i also make use of the Convert.To*** function where needed

Comment: You also should wrap your connection objects in a USING statement so they get properly closed and disposed. But glad you found a solution that works for you.